# What is a 'normal' resistance level for a closed switch?

Tags: switches, resistance, corrosion

In a closed contact or a closed switch, **theoretically, the resistance should be zero**, but in actual measurements the resistance is very close to zero but not zero.

So my question is:

What is a 'normal' resistance level in a closed switch (let's say a Push Button that works with mA currents) before it needs to be considered as useless due to corrosion etc.

Edit: The switch I'm talking about is a Push Button with integrated LED. Attached Image with schematic for more detail.

[image: Push Button Schematic]

Comment: It would depend on your design's constraints. If 100mΩ means your circuit no longer works then so be it. This is an open-ended question without more detail.

Comment: This is not a discussion forum. Your question currently appears to be an open ended question, and hence is a poor match to stackexchange. You need to improve your question, or it is likely to be closed. I recommend taking the [tour](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) or reading [help centre guidance](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on how to ask questions that are likely to get good answers.

Comment: Without the rest of your circuit, we just simply cannot help you.  This is so broad and we have so little information

Comment: The on-resistance is a parameter that can be found in any switch's datasheet. Whether or not a particular switch will work in your application *depends on your application*. There is no generic answer.

Answer (score 3):

> What is a 'normal' resistance level in a closed switch (let's say a Push Button that works with mA currents)

It should be near Zero. Specifics will depend on the specific for your switch. [The first tact switch I found on google, the Omron B3F series](http://www.omron.com/ecb/products/pdf/en-b3f.pdf) shows Contact resistance of 100 milliOhms (0.1 Ohms) **initially**. It is also only rated for 1 - 50 mA at 5 to 24VDC. It lasts a few million presses when used with 100 grams of force.

> before it needs to be considered as useless due to corrosion etc.

This is subjective. There are Two considerations.

1. Physical contact. If the switch has fused together, or has been stripped of enough metal that contact is not being made, it's useless.
2. Application sensitive.

Resistance of the contacts does not matter much in input sensing application where current flow is minimal. But it matters when being used for switching a large sensitive load.

Or when for some reason being used to switch in an analog input where the resistance is being measured. If the switch has built up more resistance than is accounted for, it will interfere with measurements. 1 to 100Ω may not matter when the measurement is looking for an order of magnitude higher (10k resistance), but if its looking for 1k resistance and your switch is now measuring 1k, that can lead to false positives.